# Dictionary creation from dataframe, replace values, remove nulls. Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose the following dataframe in which one column (`df.VALUE`) contains only string values and several other columns which contain a combination of null and floats.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'VALUE': ['A','B','C','D','E'],
    'CAT1' : [np.nan,1,1,1,1],
    'CAT2': [1,1,np.nan,np.nan,1]})
```

I'd like to create a dictionary in which the non-null for values for each column are replaced by the corresponding value from the `VALUE` column and listed with the associated column name as key:

```
{'CAT1': ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 'CAT2': ['A', 'B', 'E']}
```

So far, I achieve this using `pd.where` and the `to_dict` methods to create the dictionary. This includes null values in the lists and so a for loop with list comprehension is used to retain only the `str` values:

```
d1 = df.iloc[:,1:].where(df.isna(), df['VALUE'], axis=0).to_dict(orient='list')

for key in d1.keys():
        d1[key] = [x for x in d1[key] if type(x) == str]
```

List comprehension within a for loop doesn't seem to be the most efficient solution here and I hoped someone could suggest a more elegant approach please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a simple dictionary comprehension and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['VALUE'])
out = {c: df.loc[df[c].eq(1), 'VALUE'].tolist() for c in cols}

# or for non-NA values
out = {c: df.loc[df[c].notna(), 'VALUE'].tolist() for c in cols}
```

Output:

```
{'CAT1': ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 'CAT2': ['A', 'B', 'E']}
```

For completeness, a pure pandas approach could be:

```
out = (df.set_index('VALUE').stack().reset_index()
         .groupby('level_1', sort=False)['VALUE'].agg(list).to_dict()
      )
```

But it's very likely less efficient.

Comment: Yep, that works! Slight amendment to make it work with my actual data: `{c: df.loc[~df[c].isna(), 'VALUE'].tolist() for c in cols}`

Answer (score 2):

Another option with [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to get rid of the `NaN`*s* and [`T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) to reshape :

```
d = {}

for cat, val in df.set_index("VALUE").T.stack().index:
    d.setdefault(cat, []).append(val)

print(d) # {'CAT1': ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 'CAT2': ['A', 'B', 'E']}
```

Comment: I just added a similar alternative, however I believe that going full pandas is less efficient than using a dictionary comprehension ;)

Comment: Yes, I have this feeling too especially when `groupby` is chained with `stack`. On my machine, your 1st approach is the fatest, it takes `300 µs`, the 2nd `822 µs` and mine takes `315 µs`.